# Create a Postgresql view that restricts what a user can see

Tags: postgresql, view, permissions

I am trying to create a view that restricts the user to only see certain columns. I have granted access to these columns. But when I create the view I run into permission errors. It seems that I need to give permissions to the join columns also and this is one of the restricted columns.

Is there a way to give access to this restricted column, create the view and revoke the permission but the view will still run after the permission have been revoked?

When I revoke the permission from the underlying table the view does not run.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I guess you want a function that returns a table of columns, not the view

Comment: But I would still need to grant permissions to a join column that is restricted. So the the user could still go to the underlying table and see the restricted column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, tables are accessible to its owner only. That same owner should create the view with the columns you want to expose. You then `GRANT` permission to other users to `SELECT` against the view. This is the standard model to grant access under the SQL standard.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  pk       integer PRIMARY KEY,
  t1_col   varchar
);

CREATE TABLE t2 (
  pk       integer PRIMARY KEY,
  fk_t1    integer NOT NULL REFERENCES t1,
  t2_col   varchar,
  secret   varchar
);

CREATE VIEW exposed_columns AS
  SELECT t1_col, t2_col
  FROM t1
  JOIN t2 ON t2.fk_t1 = t1.pk;
```

All of the above are **only** available to the role that created these objects. The same owner can allow access for other roles:

```
GRANT SELECT ON exposed_columns TO some_role, another_role;
```

Users with the "some_role" or "another_role" role assigned to them can now select from the view. Other columns from the tables behind the view - e.g. the PK's, the FK and column "secret" - are not accessible but to the owner.